# Redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, redirect

I want to redirect from one domain to another
like

```
www.mydomain.com/abc/def/ghi.html
```

To this

```
www.myanotherdomain.com/index.php?c=abc&s=def&p=ghi.html
```

can anybody solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This rule will only accept URL with 3 parameters (no less, no more).
Each one can contain numbers, letters and `-` (in other words : `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ http://myanotherdomain.com/index.php?c=$1&s=$2&p=$3 [L,R=301]
```

You can modify this htaccess to allow 1, 2 OR 3 parameters :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ http://myanotherdomain.com/index.php?c=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ http://myanotherdomain.com/index.php?c=$1&s=$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ http://myanotherdomain.com/index.php?c=$1&s=$2&p=$3 [L,R=301]
```